# How to find each value of one column to the column of other data frame with different lengths of rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames, Dataframe1 which has three columns: uniquid, poistion1(x, y position) and position 2(x, y position) and Dataframe2 have four columns: Top, Bottom, Left, and Right and each column has (x, y position) values. Both dataframe has a different number of rows.

```
    DataFrame1 
Unique Id   Position 1    Position 2    
  1         (28, 50)        (49, 94)
  2         (18, 181)       (616, 90)
  3         (578, 253)      (15, 182)
  4         (600, 96)       (44, 307)

   DataFrame2
Top         Bottom          Left            Right
(25,30)     (445,25)        (846,52)        (16, 180)
(46, 307)   (569, 264)      (28, 50)        (22, 185)
(36, 201)   (95, 330)                       (49, 94)    
(600, 96)   (616, 90)
```

I want to search for each value of the position1 match in which column of Datafram2? Suppose, position1 first value (28,50) available in the Left columns of DataFrame2 then in the dataFrame1, write in the newposition1 for unique id one should write Column name+uniqueID (Ex. “Left1”). If the value is not available in any columns of Dataframe2, then write “NotFound.” And the same for position2.

Expected Output:

```
DataFrame1 
Unique Id  Position 1    Position 2   newposition1    newposition2
1          (28, 50)      (49, 94)        Left1          Right1
2          (18, 181)     (616, 90)     NotFound         Bottom2
3          (578, 253)    (15, 182)      NotFound        NotFound
4          (600, 96)     (44, 307)        Top4          NotFound
```

I tried couple of solution but didn't work for me.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: shouldn't `49,94` be `Right2`?

Comment: @Datanovice no, question requires Column name+uniqueID , we are in line with uniqueID = 1, so it is correctly ```Right1```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dataframe.melt` on df2 and `map` the values:

```
s = df2.melt().dropna().set_index("value")["variable"]

df["newpos1"] = df["Position 1"].map(s) + df["Unique Id"].astype(str)
df["newpos2"] = df["Position 2"].map(s) + df["Unique Id"].astype(str)

print (df)

   Unique Id  Position 1 Position 2 newpos1  newpos2
0          1    (28, 50)   (49, 94)   Left1   Right1
1          2   (18, 181)  (616, 90)     NaN  Bottom2
2          3  (578, 253)  (15, 182)     NaN      NaN
3          4   (600, 96)  (44, 307)    Top4      NaN
```